# Append a numpy array with different first dimensions

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, append, concatenation

My program creates a numpy array within a for loop. For example it creates array with shape `(100*30*10)`, then `(160*30*10)` and then may be `(120*30*10)` . I have to append the above to an empty numpy array such that , at the end of the loop, it will be a numpy  array with shape `(380*30*10)` (i.e sum  of 100+160+120) . The second and third dimension doesnt change in the numpy array.

How can I do the above in python. I tried the following.

```
np_model = np.append(np_model,np_temp1)
print("Appended model shape is",np_model.shape)
np_label = np.append(np_label,np_temp2)
print("Appended label shape is",np_label.shape)
```

The `np_model` is an empty array which I have defined as `np_model = np.empty(1,30,10)` and np_label as `np_label = np.empty(1 ,str)`

`np_temp1` corresponds to array within each for loop like `100*30*10`,`120*30*10` etc and `np_temp2` is a string with "item1","item2" etc

The `np_label` is a string numpy array with 1 label corresponding to `np_temp1.shape[0]`. But the result I get in np_model is flattened array with size `380*30*10` = `1140000`

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you're looking for `np.stack()`, specifically `np.vstack()`

Comment: So , how should I define the empty array?

Comment: why do you need an empty array?

Comment: You shouldn't be using array append repeatedly. Make a list first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use numpy `concatenate` function, append the output numpy(s) to a list and then feed it to the `concatenate` function:

```
empty_list = []
x = np.zeros([10, 20, 4])
y = np.zeros([12, 20, 4])
empty_list.append(x)
empty_list.append(y)
z = np.concatenate(empty_list, axis=0)
print(x.shape, y.shape, z.shape)
```

> (10, 20, 4) (12, 20, 4) (22, 20, 4)

Comment: But initially,my array is empty. How can I concatenate an empty numpy array with non empty array

Comment: @RamShankerG , append them to an empty list. Check my code (edited).

Answer (score 0):

As @Nullman suggested in comment(`np.vstack`)

You can create empty array like this `>>> np_model = np.empty((0,30,10))`

```py
>>> np_model = np.empty((0,30,10))

>>> a = np.random.rand(100,30,10)
>>> b = np.random.rand(160,30,10)
>>> c = np.random.rand(120,30,10)

# It can done by one-line like`np_model = np.vstack((a,b,c))`
# but i guess you have loop dependency here
>>> np_model = np.vstack((np_model,a))
>>> np_model = np.vstack((np_model,b))
>>> np_model = np.vstack((np_model,c))

>>> np_model.shape
(380, 30, 10)
```

Comment: do one vstack at the end

Answer (score 0):

To specifically answer your question towards starting with an empty array, that'd be my solution, solely using [`np.concatenate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html):

```py
import numpy as np

# Some arrays to append in a loop
arrays = (
    np.random.rand(100, 30, 10),
    np.random.rand(160, 30, 10),
    np.random.rand(120, 30, 10)
)

# Initial empty array
array = np.zeros((0, 30, 10))

# Appending arrays in loop
for a in arrays:
    array = np.concatenate((array, a), axis=0)

# Output shape
print(array.shape)
```

Output:

```
(380, 30, 10)
```

Hope that helps!

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:    Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
Python:      3.8.1
NumPy:       1.18.1
----------------------------------------
```

Comment: list append is faster

Comment: @hpaulj I had concerns regarding "collecting" all single arrays and using just a single `np.concatenate`, because you'd need twice the memory of the final array (since you store all intermediate arrays in the list), which wouldn't be the case in my suggested solution - assuming, the arrays to be appended are generated (and deleted/overwritten/...) on-the-fly in the mentioned loop, which is, how I understood the question. So, depending on the amount and size of the actual arrays, "collecting" them might lead to memory issues.

Comment: With your iteration doesn't save on memory, and does a whole lot more copying.